# Why am I getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this Java program?

Tags: java, io, indexoutofboundsexception

In Java, I am doing some work with RandomAccessFile. I have a file that is 8192 bytes, or 8kb.

The following is causing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
File file = new File("TestFile1");
raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
byte[] temp = new byte[4096];
raf.read(temp, 4096, 4096);
```

Even something like this causes the same error:

```
raf.read(temp, 4096, 1);
```

Though something like this works perfectly:

```
raf.read(temp, 0, 4096);
```

When I run the following, I get 8192, which is why I am confused as to why this is not working:

```
System.out.println(raf.getChannel().size());
```

Why am I getting an out of bounds error if I try to read from the second half of the file?

Comment: Please tell us and show us what bp1 is. This seems to be a key bit of information that you're hiding from us.

Comment: @matheszabi: I down-voted the question because as asked it was too ambiguous, leaving out key bits of information. It has since been corrected and the down-vote removed.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of:

```
raf.getBytes(temp,4096,4096);
```

it sounds like you want:

```
raf.seek(4096); raf.getBytes(temp,0,4096);
```

The second parameter of `getBytes` gives the offset into the buffer into which the content will be read, not the offset into the file.

Comment: Fixed my original post, could you maybe update yours accordingly? Though I think the changes are minimal, and I believe I get what you're saying.

Comment: Ah, so my issue was that I was telling it to start writing into temp at index 4096, causing the out of bounds exception?

Comment: Yes, you were attempting to read content into the area beyond the end of `temp`.  This is why, for example, `raf.getBytes(temp,4095,1)` would work but `raf.getBytes(temp,4095,2)` wouldn't.